# <SomeModule> is not an Angular module

Tags: angular, webstorm

When using an Angular project, I am importing the core Angular NgModules, and Webstorm is telling me that they are not valid Angular modules.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, // Gets the error
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        HttpClientModule, // Gets the error
        UpgradeModule, // Gets the error
        CoreModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

All of the modules that I am importing into my `app.module` are getting a red-squiggle saying that they are not an Angular module. I can't stand to look at the code with this. Has anyone seen this before? Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got on a Google Hangout with the webstorm team and they saw that none of my `node_modules` were being indexed. I opened up my project preferences and removed `node_modules` from my excluded directories. Totally worked.

- Hit `Command + ,` to open Preferences.
- Search for `Directories` in your left preferences menu.
- Remove `node_modules` from the excluded section on the right.
- Save and Apply changes
- Wait for Webstorm to re-index the project and node modules.

It worked.

Comment: Wow, I always exclude my node_modules from webstorm because otherwise, the IDE drags drags drags.  Times have changed I guess if they are recommending this.

Comment: Even though you don't exclude node_modules, Webstorm (and Jetbrains IDEs) will not fully index them. They only index the packages in your package.json, or if it is a TS dependency, it will transitively index nested TS deps, cause they are easy to index. 

So, while you don't exclude them specifically, Webstorm IDE is optimized to largely ignore the node modules. But in some cases, it needs the ones referenced in your package.json.

Comment: I had to restart WebStorm as it did not index automatically.  Worked after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same issue when I had a typo in my `package.json`. Webstorm (and all JetBrains IDEs) look at the `package.json` to see what the top-level `node_modules` are cause it will index those. If there is a typo in your package.json, you will get an error like this.

In my case, I was missing an missing commas.