# class MatButtonModule is not an angular module

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the hardware buttons in my application but I get an error saying the class MatButtonModule is not an angular module. I don't know where I was wrong

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UquPz.png)

Comment: Its angular/ material button . you need to import this inside your module

Comment: ng add @angular/material Please check https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It _looks_ like you are using an IntelliJ IDE. Have you seen the accepted answer from a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168593/1285763? In case it doesn't help, could you edit your question to include the code as a text? That would help others find your question.

Comment: @alphiii this is what I did and @ angular/material installed correctly

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Already done but the error is still there